# SSL Error in python 2.7.5 version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, openssl, urllib2, boto3

I tried to collect AWS guard duty logs using `boto3` library, I was able to fetch logs using Python 3.6 version but was throwing up some annoying errors while using Python 2.7.5.

The error message was:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Python 2, out of interest?  Is this an old project?

Comment: Yes, we are having a project skeleton built on Python 2.7.5

Comment: That seems like a new thing though - that's present tense.  I would recommend STRONGLY against starting any new project in Python 2.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*